# Heroku hobby dyno and free database?

Tags: heroku

I want to purchase a heroku hobby dyno ($ 7) for a small project and I need a database, a free heroku postgres add-on suits me, but the hobby dyno specifications indicate that `Cannot combine with other dyno types`. Does this mean that I will not be able to use the free database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynos and addons are separate things. You can definitely use a free Heroku Postgres plan with a hobby dyno.

You may need a larger [Heroku Postgres plan](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql#pricing) if you are approaching the limits of the free plan (currently 10,000 rows and 1GB of storage), but this is unrelated to your dyno types.